# Printer & Scanner Epson XP-245

Tags: printing, scanner, epson

I just bought an Epson xp-245 and for some reasons I cannot connect it to Ubuntu... I don't have any problem for my printer to appear on the computer and to connect it through USB, but when I try to print the pages come out with MMMMMMMM on the side of the sheet, or some numbers and letters, not at all what I'm trying to print.

Any idea how to solve that?

And also I cannot connect my scanner (I'm using gscan and it says it doesn't find any scanner)

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: did you install the linux drivers from epson?

Comment: Yes I did... I installed the generic driver

Comment: What about dowloading the Scanner Drivers from [here](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/du/02/DriverDownloadInfo.do?LG2=DE&CN2=&DSCMI=70163&DSCCHK=b094ba2ad41b14121d6fcce6e0f3fbdcaa7dfbfa)?

Answer (score 1):

I have access to an XP245 printer. It uses a WiFi connection and connects without any fiddling by me. Just has a power socket, nothing else I could find.

Epson support has a Linux Scanner package available for download, which is easy to find. There's a specific scan utility, or you go through SANE. The printing is handled by a separate module. The scanner-only page is a bit too easy to find, best go to the printer-specific driver downloads, where you can get both.

Start from this link: http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/

Search for "XP-245" in this case, and you get a list of drivers, Windows, Mac, and Linux. Both the Printer and Scanner drivers should appear. For printing you also need to install LSB via your usual OS method.

I am only borrowing this box to get some scanning done, and I initially wondered if there was any Linux printer driver.

Comment: It's important to search for "XP-245" exactly, since other permutations do not show any results.